# Rename URL in address bar, not the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So basically I want to change only the url that shows in address bar, not the href location.

For example, I have this link:

```
https://www.example.com/pagenumber1
```

I want to rename the url address to this:

```
https://www.example.com/anothertext
```

But the page to remain intact, and also the page to be only accessed from the first list (/pagenumber1) if it is possible.

Comment: use `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState`..    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the state of the [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) property:

```
window.history.pushState({test:1}, null, '?test=1');
```